# How to stop adding the same item in array while browser reload in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, browser

In my ASP.NET project, I add a new array item with the help of query string. once the array item added, my client reload the browser,. so the same item add another time. It happens each reload timing.

but i don't want this. any possible to stop this browser reload or stop the same array item?

my url is -

```
51402/ItemGrid.aspx?id=3035
```

then `id=3035` item added to the array.

My Code in page load event

```
string query ="";
            int array_no;
            if (Convert.ToUInt32(GlobalClass.GlobalarrayNo.ToString()) == 0)
            {
                array_no = 0;
                Array.Clear(roomno, 0, roomno.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                array_no = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalClass.GlobalarrayNo.ToString());
            }
            id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {               
                // ******* Happy Status ************

                decimal happyfromtime = 0;
                string happyper="";             
                string happytotime = "";
                query = "SELECT Parameters_Parameter3,Parameters_Parameter2,Parameters_Parameter1,Parameters_Parameter4 FROM MCS_Parameters WHERE Parameters_TYPE ='HAPHOU'";
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalClass.GlobalConnString.ToString());
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    happyfromtime= Convert.ToDecimal(Reader[0].ToString());
                    happyper=Reader[1].ToString();
                    happystatus= Convert.ToInt32(Reader[2].ToString());
                    happytotime = Reader[3].ToString();
                }
                connection.Close();

                string t = GlobalClass.GlobalserverTime.ToString();
                t= t.Substring(0,5);
                t = t.Replace(":",".");

                //ALLTRIM(CurCate.Fb_Item_Creation_HappyhoursStatus)='Yes'
                if ((Convert.ToDecimal(t) > Convert.ToDecimal(happyfromtime)) && (Convert.ToDecimal(t) < Convert.ToDecimal(happytotime)) && (happystatus == 1))                
                {
                    tHappy_Status = 1;
                }

                if (GlobalClass.GlobalservedAt == "RST")
                {
                    query = "select a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemDescription, a.Fb_Item_Creation_RestaurantPrice, a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCode, a.Fb_Item_Creation_TaxStatus, "
                            + "a.Fb_Item_Creation_VatPercentage, a.Fb_Item_Creation_ServicechargeStatus, a.Fb_Item_Creation_SurchargeStatus, a.Fb_Item_Creation_DiscountStatus,"
                            + "a.FB_Item_ID, b.Fb_Category_Stock, b.Fb_Category_Name,a.Fb_Item_Creation_ModifierStatus,a.Fb_Item_Creation_HappyhoursStatus from fb_item_creation a, fb_category b "
                            + "where a.FB_Item_ID = '" + id + "' and a.Fb_Item_Creation_DeleteStatus=0 and "
                            + "a.Fb_Item_Creation_OutletId='" + GlobalClass.GlobaloutletId + "' "
                            + "and a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemGroupId='" + GlobalClass.GlobalitemGroupId + "' and b.Fb_Category_DeleteStatus=0 and "
                            + "b.Fb_Category_Id = a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCategoryId";
                }
                else if (GlobalClass.GlobalservedAt == "BAR")
                {
                    query = "select a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemDescription, a.Fb_Item_Creation_BarPrice, a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCode, a.Fb_Item_Creation_TaxStatus, "
                            + "a.Fb_Item_Creation_VatPercentage, a.Fb_Item_Creation_ServicechargeStatus, a.Fb_Item_Creation_SurchargeStatus, a.Fb_Item_Creation_DiscountStatus,"
                            + "a.FB_Item_ID, b.Fb_Category_Stock, b.Fb_Category_Name,a.Fb_Item_Creation_ModifierStatus,a.Fb_Item_Creation_HappyhoursStatus,a.Fb_Item_Creation_HappyhoursStatus from fb_item_creation a, fb_category b "
                            + "where a.FB_Item_ID = '" + id + "' and a.Fb_Item_Creation_DeleteStatus=0 and "
                            + "a.Fb_Item_Creation_OutletId='" + GlobalClass.GlobaloutletId + "' "
                            + "and a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemGroupId='" + GlobalClass.GlobalitemGroupId + "' and b.Fb_Category_DeleteStatus=0 and "
                            + "b.Fb_Category_Id = a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCategoryId";
                }
                else
                {
                    query = "select a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemDescription, a.Fb_Item_Creation_RoomPrice, a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCode, a.Fb_Item_Creation_TaxStatus, "
                            + "a.Fb_Item_Creation_VatPercentage, a.Fb_Item_Creation_ServicechargeStatus, a.Fb_Item_Creation_SurchargeStatus, a.Fb_Item_Creation_DiscountStatus,"
                            + "a.FB_Item_ID, b.Fb_Category_Stock, b.Fb_Category_Name,a.Fb_Item_Creation_ModifierStatus from fb_item_creation a, fb_category b "
                            + "where a.FB_Item_ID = '" + id + "' and a.Fb_Item_Creation_DeleteStatus=0 and "
                            + "a.Fb_Item_Creation_OutletId='" + GlobalClass.GlobaloutletId + "' "
                            + "and a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemGroupId='" + GlobalClass.GlobalitemGroupId + "' and b.Fb_Category_DeleteStatus=0 and "
                            + "b.Fb_Category_Id = a.Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCategoryId";
                }
                connection = new MySqlConnection(GlobalClass.GlobalConnString.ToString());

                command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    roomno[array_no, 0] = Reader[0].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_ItemDescription
                    if (GlobalClass.GlobalopenCode == "OPEN")
                    {

                        roomno[array_no, 0] = GlobalClass.GlobalopenDes.ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_ItemDescription
                        roomno[array_no, 1] = GlobalClass.GlobalopenRate.ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_RoomPrice
                        roomno[array_no, 2] = GlobalClass.GlobalopenQty.ToString();                // Qty
                        roomno[array_no, 3] = Reader[2].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCode
                        roomno[array_no, 4] = Reader[3].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_TaxStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 5] = Reader[4].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_VatPercentage
                        roomno[array_no, 6] = Reader[5].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_ServicechargeStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 7] = Reader[6].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_SurchargeStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 8] = Reader[7].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_DiscountStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 9] = Reader[8].ToString(); // FB_Item_ID
                        roomno[array_no, 10] = Reader[9].ToString(); // Fb_Category_Stock
                        roomno[array_no, 11] = Reader[10].ToString(); // Fb_Category_Name
                        roomno[array_no, 12] = Reader[1].ToString();  // Total = rate * qty
                        roomno[array_no, 13] = Reader[11].ToString(); //Fb_Item_Creation_ModifierStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 14] = ""; //Fb_Kot_Item_TouchLine
                        roomno[array_no, 15] = ""; // UserModifier
                        roomno[array_no, 16] = Reader[12].ToString(); // HappyHours


                        array_no++;
                        GlobalClass.GlobalarrayNo = array_no;
                    }
                    else if (roomno[array_no, 0] == "OPEN")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("OpenItem.aspx" + "?id=" + id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        roomno[array_no, 1] = Reader[1].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_RoomPrice
                        roomno[array_no, 2] = "1";                  // Qty
                        roomno[array_no, 3] = Reader[2].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_ItemCode
                        roomno[array_no, 4] = Reader[3].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_TaxStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 5] = Reader[4].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_VatPercentage
                        roomno[array_no, 6] = Reader[5].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_ServicechargeStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 7] = Reader[6].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_SurchargeStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 8] = Reader[7].ToString(); // Fb_Item_Creation_DiscountStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 9] = Reader[8].ToString(); // FB_Item_ID
                        roomno[array_no, 10] = Reader[9].ToString(); // Fb_Category_Stock
                        roomno[array_no, 11] = Reader[10].ToString(); // Fb_Category_Name
                        roomno[array_no, 12] = Reader[1].ToString();  // Total = rate * qty
                        roomno[array_no, 13] = Reader[11].ToString(); //Fb_Item_Creation_ModifierStatus
                        roomno[array_no, 14] = ""; //Fb_Kot_Item_TouchLine
                        roomno[array_no, 15] = ""; // UserModifier                        
                        roomno[array_no, 16] = Reader[12].ToString(); // HappyHours

                        if ((tHappy_Status == 1) && (roomno[array_no, 16].ToString()=="Yes"))
                        {
                            roomno[array_no, 8] = "Yes";
                        }

                        array_no++;
                        GlobalClass.GlobalarrayNo = array_no;

                        //var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
                        //nameValues.Set("sortBy", "4");
                        //string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                        //string updatedQueryString = "?" + nameValues.ToString();
                        //Response.Redirect(url + updatedQueryString);
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();

                ViewState["btn"] = "1";
                ViewState["tot"] = "0";
                ViewState["happystatus"] = happystatus;
                btn_click = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["btn"].ToString());
                int len = array_no;
                while (len > 8)
                {
                    len = len - 8;
                    tot++;
                }

                if (len != 0) tot++;
                ViewState["tot"] = tot;
                fun();
                //CreatingTmpModdbf1();

                // Modifier Text
                int seq = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["seq"]);
                string text = Request.QueryString["text"];
                if (text != null)
                {
                    roomno[seq - 1, 15] = text;
                }
            }
```

!postback is not help to avoid my problem.

```
static class GlobalClass
    {
        private static string myConnString1 = "";
        private static int userId = 0;
        private static string userName = "";
        private static int outletId = 0;
        private static int itemGroupId = 0;
        private static DateTime serverDate;
        private static string serverTime = "";
        private static string tableName = "";
        private static string serverdAt = "";
        private static int arrayNo = 0;
        private static int waiterId = 0;
        private static int covers = 0;
        private static string kotno = "";


        public static string GlobalConnString
        {
            get { return myConnString1; }
            set { myConnString1 = value; }                     
        }

        public static int GlobaluserId
        {
            get { return userId;}
            set { userId = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobaluserName
        {
            get { return userName; }
            set { userName = value; }
        }

        public static int GlobaloutletId
        {
            get { return outletId; }
            set { outletId = value; }
        }

        public static DateTime GlobalserverDate
        {
            get { return serverDate; }
            set { serverDate = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobalserverTime
        {
            get { return serverTime; }
            set { serverTime = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobaltableName
        {
            get { return tableName; }
            set { tableName = value; }
        }

        public static int GlobalitemGroupId
        {
            get { return itemGroupId; }
            set { itemGroupId = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobalservedAt
        {
            get { return serverdAt; }
            set { serverdAt = value; }
        }

        public static int GlobalarrayNo
        {
            get { return arrayNo; }
            set { arrayNo = value; }
        }

        public static int GlobalwaiterId
        {
            get { return waiterId; }
            set { waiterId = value; }
        }

        public static int Globalcovers
        {
            get { return covers; }
            set { covers = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobalkotNo
        {
            get { return kotno ; }
            set { kotno = value; }
        }

        public static string staffId = "";
        public static string staffCategoryId = "";

        public static string GlobalstaffId
        {
            get { return staffId; }
            set { staffId = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobalstaffCategoryId
        {
            get { return staffCategoryId; }
            set { staffCategoryId = value; }
        }

        public static string openCode = "";
        public static string openDes = "";

        public static string GlobalopenCode
        {
            get { return openCode; }
            set { openCode = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobalopenDes
        {
            get { return openDes; }
            set { openDes = value; }
        }

        public static string openQty = "";
        public static string openRate = "";

        public static string GlobalopenQty
        {
            get { return openQty; }
            set { openQty = value; }
        }

        public static string GlobalopenRate
        {
            get { return openRate; }
            set { openRate = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Search an element, if it *exists* in an array then don't *set* it.

Comment: Show us also the _relevant_ code of `GlobalClass` (it sounds like it uses static variables which is a very bad idea in asp.net since every user would use the same).

Comment: @timschmelter why?. Is i want to change the code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your array is static/shared. Static variables are shared across the whole app domain and all threads. Hence every user uses the same variable.

Don't use static variables therefor, instead of persisting the array you should use the querystring again.

<sub>If this was a wrong assumption you should show us your code</sub>

Answer (score 0):

After adding item you can redirect to another page. For example 51402/ItemGrid.aspx

Also using get request to save/edit/delete data is not good idea, better use post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the item to the Array within Page_Load, you may want to wrap the code that adds the item in the following:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    //Your array item adding code here
End If
```

This will prevent the item adding again if the user refreshes the page. Though, I'd like to echo Tim and say that if I assumed incorrectly, you should post your code.